# Difference between <T> and <E>

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

What's the main difference between a generics T and E. I have a method which return a variable of type T, and I have another method which creates a ArrayList. My other question is: Is it safe to just cast the variable to (E) when adding the element to the ArrayList?

//Returns an Arraylist containing all elements in the tree in pre order Traversal

```
    public ArrayList<E> getPreorderTraversal()
```

}

This is found in the Node Class

```
public T getData();
```

Comment: Without context this is impossible to answer with certainty. T and E just represent a type; any type if they don't have bounds attached to them. It's more than likely unsafe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, there's no difference between the T and E- they're just using different names for the type parameter (E or T).

The most commonly used type parameter names are:

```
E - Element (used extensively by the Java Collections Framework)
K - Key
N - Number
T - Type
V - Value
```

Well, It would not recommend to cast variables to E without knowing whole context.

I assume if you writing BST code, you solution should be like

```
public E getData();
```

or

```
public ArrayList<T> getPreorderTraversal()
```

so node list is either type T or E. it can not contain list of Type T and return E vice versa.

Comment: It should be noted that the above conventions shouldn't be relied upon to know whether or not you should cast them. If you don't know for certainty what type something is, you shouldn't cast it.

Comment: Oh I get it!, Well I'm trying to do a Binary Search Tree, so I have a Node class which has a method which returns the data inside that Node. But I'm having trouble with a method which creates the an ArrayList<E> in pre order traversal without taking any parameters.

Comment: it'd be easier to help if you can share code.

Comment: Just edited my post.

Comment: I suppose it should be like  public E getData(); or  public ArrayList<T> getPreorderTraversal()